# org-latex-fragment gets cutoff

Tags: latex, images, preview-latex

I use dvisvgm to generate latex fragments. However, some of my equations seem to be cut off. One example is below

[image: Equation that get cuts off]

The svg file generated does not have the cutoff but the image as displayed in emacs does. I have tried rescaling the images (using org-format-latex-options) and also changing the org-format-latex-header, but have had no success so far. If you have any idea on what might be causing the discrepancy please comment back.

Comment: Did you already try dvisvgm option `--exact` or just `-e`? Some glyphs exceed the bounding box specified by the TFM data so that the graphics get clipped. Option `--exact` should prevent this problem.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the response. I am not sure how to specify dvisvgm options. I changed the org-preview-latex-default-process to dvisvgm --exact and got the error "org-format-latex: Unknown conversion process dvisvgm --exact for LaTeX fragments". Previously I had this set to just "dvisvgm". Please let me know if you have any insights on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an Org expert. I don't know if or where the dvisvgm options can be configured. Maybe `org-preview-latex-process-alist` has to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: If you still have the problem, you should try the answer below: it implements @Martin's suggestion, so it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reading comments, the first thing you should do is read the documentation of `org-preview-latex-process-alist`. How? Do `C-h v org-preview-latex-process-alist RET`. This will familiarise you with how Emacs actually makes those svg images. Then once you know what you are doing, this code will make more sense.

The default value of `preview-latex-process-alist` is something like this,

```lisp
((dvipng :programs
          ("latex" "dvipng")
          :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
          (1.0 . 1.0)
          :latex-compiler
          ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("dvipng -fg %F -bg %B -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
           ("latex" "dvisvgm")
           :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
           (1.7 . 1.5)
           :latex-compiler
           ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
           :image-converter
           ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
               ("latex" "convert")
               :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
               (1.0 . 1.0)
               :latex-compiler
               ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
               :image-converter
               ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Since you are using svg images (good choice!) the element that pertains to you is,

```lisp
 (dvisvgm :programs
           ("latex" "dvisvgm")
           :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
           (1.7 . 1.5)
           :latex-compiler
           ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
           :image-converter
           ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
```

We need to edit the `:image-converter ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O")` part as suggested by @Martin in the comments. Instead of changing the element already in `org-preview-latex-process-alist`, I decided to make a new one and add that in the list. Here is how that is done,

```lisp
(setq my:dvi-to-svg
    (my:dvi-to-svg :programs
        ("latex" "dvisvgm")
           :description "dvi > svg"
           :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm."
           :use-xcolor t
           :image-input-type "dvi"
           :image-output-type "svg"
           :image-size-adjust (1.7 . 1.5)
           :latex-compiler ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
           :image-converter ("dvisvgm %f -e -n -b min -c %S -o %O")))
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
    (add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist my:dvi-to-svg)
    (setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'my:dvi-to-svg))
```

Now in your document put `#+OPTIONS: tex:my:dvi-to-svg`. Now you can change anything about `my:dvi-to-svg`.